# One God Ray Effect

Tags: python

I am setting up lighting for a scene and I want one light to have a *god ray* effect. However, when I use *volume scatter* on the scene it works for ALL lights. How do I isolate a spot light source for this effect or if there is any other way please let me know.

Comment: Hello, you've tagged your question as Python, is it the case? If you're using a Spot light, you could create a volume that has the same shape as the Spot cone. Or you can create the shape and use a mix between Emission and Transparent with a (Input) Layer Weight node as factor

Comment: Or you could use light groups...